# What is the pythonic way of "iterating" over a single item?

Tags: python, numpy

I come across this issue often, and I would be surprised if there wasn't some very simple and pythonic one-liner solution to it.

Suppose I have a method or a function that takes a list or some other iterable object as an argument. I want for an operation to be performed once for each item in the object.

Sometimes, only a single item (say, a float value) is passed to this function. In this situation, my for-loop doesn't know what to do. And so, I find myself peppering my code with the following snippet of code:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence

def my_function(value):
   if not isinstance(value, Sequence):
      value = [value]

   # rest of my function
```

This works, but it seems wasteful and not particularly legible. In searching StackOverflow I've also discovered that strings are considered sequences, and so this code could easily break given the wrong argument. It just doesn't feel like the right approach.

I come from a MATLAB background, and this is neatly solved in that language since scalars are treated like 1x1 matrices. I'd expect, at the very least, for there to be a built-in, something like numpy's [atleast_1d function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_1d.html), that automatically converts anything into an iterable if it isn't one.

Comment: I think it's pretty reasonable to just expect callers to pass in a 1 element array when they want to operate on a collection of just 1 thing. In languages that aren't "matrix based" (MatLab, R, APL, etc.), it's pretty typical for a function to A) either just operate on one thing, or B) operate on a collection of things. If a caller wants to use function A on multiple things, they can just use `map` or a list comprehension to apply the function to each element.  If a callers want to use function B on a single thing, they can just pass a one-element array.

Comment: I'm sad to hear this. I find this to be an ugly design-choice.

Comment: It might feel that way, coming from a MatLab background that's ingrained a certain expectation, but it has upsides. As an example, consider that in Python, `+` can be used for list concatenation, which is something that's done much more frequently than element-wise additions of two lists. The nice/pretty syntax of `a = b + c` can be applied for this more common use case, so `[1, 2] + [3, 4] == [1, 2, 3, 4]`. Likewise, `"a" + "b"` gives you `"ab"`, whereas in MatLab, `"a" + "b"` gives you `196`. Surprise! (it's the sum of their ASCII codes, 97 + 98)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is nope, there is no simple built-in. And yep, if you want `str` (or `bytes` or bytes-like stuff or whatever) to act as a scalar value, it gets uglier. Python expects callers to adhere to the interface contract; if you say you accept sequences, say so, and it's on the caller to wrap any individual arguments.

If you must do this, there's two obvious ways to do it:

First is to make your function accept varargs instead of a single argument, and leave it up to the caller to unpack any sequences, so you can always iterate the varargs received:

```
def my_function(*values):
    for val in values:
        # Rest of function
```

A caller with individual items calls you with `my_function(a, b)`, a caller with a sequence calls you with `my_function(*seq)`. The latter does incur some overhead to unpack the sequence to a new `tuple` to be received by `my_function`, but in many cases this is fine.

If that's not acceptable for whatever reason, the other solution is to roll your own "ensure iterable" converter function, following whatever rules you care about:

```
from collections.abc import ByteString

def ensure_iterable(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, (str, ByteString)):
        return (obj,)  # Treat strings and bytes-like stuff as scalars and wrap
    try:
        iter(obj)  # Simplest way to test if something is iterable is to try to make it an iterator
    except TypeError:
        return (obj,)  # Not iterable, wrap
    else:
        return obj  # Already iterable
```

which `my_function` can use with:

```
def my_function(value):
   value = ensure_iterable(value)
```

Comment: While this does answer the question at face-value, I think it's worth emphasizing that the goal shouldn't be to build abstractions in Python that help you write Python as a watered-down MatLab. It just won't wor all that well, and it'll be contrary to the expectations of other Python developers.

Comment: I'll note, in practice, I've used option #1, but never used option #2. Option #1 is the Pythonic solution in some cases, option #2 never is.

Comment: ____ Yep, agreed

Comment: @Alexander: Sure. I was literally just typing a comment to that effect. There are reasonable, Pythonic, use cases for writing a function that can work on an arbitrary number of arguments via varargs, but the `ensure_iterable` here is a hack I'd only use for personal utility libraries where I know it's a hack and never expose it to anyone else.

Comment: How about `return iter(obj)` (and removing the `else`)?

Comment: @KellyBundy: I was trying to leave it unchanged if possible. It hardly matter most of the time, but that's one reasonable way to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Python is a general purpose language, with true scalars, and as well as iterables like lists.

MATLAB does not have true scalars.  The base object is a 2d matrix.  It did not start as a general purpose language.

`numpy` adds MATLAB like arrays to Python, but it too can have 0d arrays (`scalar arrays`), which may give the wayward MATLAB users headaches.

Many `numpy` functions have a provision for converting their input to an array.  That way they will work  a list input as well as array

```
In [10]: x = np.array(3)
In [11]: x
Out[11]: array(3)
In [12]: x.shape
Out[12]: ()
In [13]: for i in x: print(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [13] in <cell line: 1>
    for i in x: print(x)
TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

It also has utility functions that insure the array is 1d, or 2 ...

```
In [14]: x = np.atleast_1d(1)
In [15]: x
Out[15]: array([1])
In [16]: for i in x: print(i)
1
```

But like old-fashion MATLAB, we prefer to avoid iteration in `numpy`.  It doesn't have `jit` compilation that lets current MATLAB users get by with iterations.  Technically `numpy` functions do use iteration, but it usually in compiled code.

`np.sin` applied to various inputs:

```
In [17]: np.sin(1)          # scalar
Out[17]: 0.8414709848078965
In [18]: np.sin([1,2,3])    # list
Out[18]: array([0.84147098, 0.90929743, 0.14112001])
In [19]: np.sin(np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(3,1))
Out[19]: 
array([[0.84147098],
       [0.90929743],
       [0.14112001]])
```

Technically, the [17] result is a `numpy scalar`, not a base python float:

```
In [20]: type(Out[17])
Out[20]: numpy.float64
```

Answer (score 0):

I would duck type:

```
def first(item):
    try:
        it=iter(item)
    except TypeError:
        it=iter([item])
    return next(it)
```

Test it:

```
tests=[[1,2,3],'abc',1,1.23]

for e in tests:
    print(e, first(e))
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 3] 1
abc a
1 1
1.23 1.23
```

Comment: You misunderstood the question. They "want for an operation to be performed once **for each item in the object**". Not just for the first. Also, it's mishandling strings.